# JAR exits after the first class is complete

Tags: java, jar

I have two classes. I created a JAR file using:

```
jar cvf practice.jar class1.class class2.class
```

Then I set the starting entry point:

```
jar cfe practice.jar class1 class1.class
```

When I execute the JAR file, it works fine until the point where there is a transition to the next class, i.e. `class2 hey = new class2();` Then it exits out. But want to continue to the next class.

It should go to class2.class. Since it is saying in that object. Apparently, it does not.

```
public class class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is class 1", "Order",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        class2 hey = new class2();
    }
}

public class class2 {

    public class2() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is class 2", "Order",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include some of the code from class1 and class2?

Comment: Please show your source code and any error message you're getting.

Comment: For the sake of the community you should name the title something meaningful

Comment: simplified coding. The jar file exits out after the first class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your example and I get a NoClassDefFound for `class2` after pressing "OK" in the first window.  That is because the `class2.class` is not present in the `practice.jar` file.

Try the following instead of both your `jar ...` commands:

```
jar cfe practice.jar class1 class1.class class2.class
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making a new instance of the object class2 but if there's nothing in the constructor nothing will happen, my guess is that you have code in another method in class2 that you need to call?

I guess it would also be helpful to know what you mean by "exits out."

Comment: I meant it just feels as if t undertook System.exit(0); automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The only code written in class2 is in the main method, this method is not executed when creating an instance of that class. If you either move the code to the constructor or call the main method:

```
public class Class1 {

public Class1() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is class 1", "Order",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();
    Class2 c2 = new Class2();
}
```

}

```
public class Class2 {
public Class2() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is class 2", "Order",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```

}

Comment: 'The only code written in class2 is in the main method' - that is not what I see in the original question. He has a constructor in `class2`.